# Firefox - iTunes application detector

Tags: 12.04, itunes

in my Firefox under Plugins i have a "iTunes Application Detector". I know, I can disable it but how to remove it? Btw. how could it get there? Was it eventually restored by Firefox sync?

Anyway, there is no iTunes in Linux and I dont use iTunes. So how to get rid of it?

Comment: What version of Firefox? I'm on the latest stable (16.0.1) and I don't have this.

Comment: I'm curious why you're removing it. What problems does it cause? It should be on a standard installation, and it is useful for two things: When you go to a iTunes podcast or iTunesU podcast, it doesn't redirect to the "Install iTunes" page (which is useless for Ubuntu), and it enables sending it to Tunesviewer or Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plugin is installed by the music player. Removing the package `rhythmbox-mozilla` uninstalls the plugin.